# Accessing Public State Variables Between Contracts - Solidity - Error

Tags: solidity

I have an error accessing a public variable between contracts. It works if I change x.myname to x.myname() but I do not understand why that works. Can anyone explain why the () are needed?

Here is the code which fails -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract MyAddr {
uint public myname=1;
function getName() view  public returns (uint name) {
name = myname;
}
}
contract MyAddr2 {
MyAddr private x;
string private myname1;
  function getStateVar() view public returns (uint stateVar) {
       stateVar = x.myname;
   }
}

contract MyAddr3 {
}

MyAddr.sol:12:20: Error: Type function () view external returns 
(uint256) is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256.
    stateVar = x.myname;
               ^------^


x.myname to x.myname() does work.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a `public` state variable, the `public` part is that a corresponding getter—a function that returns the state variable's value—with the same name as the variable is created. So the way to access the value from outside the contract is to call that function.

See https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/02/making-smart-contracts-with-public-variables/, https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters, and http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#getter-functions.